# Incorporating an additional graphics element when using Animate and ParametricPlot3D

Tags: graphics, animation

I'm trying to animate some curves that wrap around a cylinder. OK so far:

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[α t], Sin[α t], 
Sqrt[1 - α^2] t}, {Cos[α t], 
Sin[α t], -Sqrt[1 - α^2] t}}, {α, -1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2 π, 2 π}}], {t, 0, 
2 π}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

But I'm struggling to incorporate the cylinder itself:

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2 π}, {0, 0, 2 π}}, 1]]
```

You can probably see the problem: the curves run around an invisible cylinder. I'd be much happier if I could see it! I've tried to squeeze the cylinder in in a few different ways (putting it into the `Animate[ParametricPlot3D[...]]` in different places, and using `Epilog`), but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to include a `Show`:

```
Animate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[α t], Sin[α t], 
      Sqrt[1 - α^2] t}, {Cos[α t], 
      Sin[α t], -Sqrt[1 - α^2] t}}, {α, -1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2 π, 2 π}}], 

    Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2 π}, {0, 0, 2 π}}, 1]]
  ], 
{t, 0, 2 π}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

`Show` returns a graphics object that can be further customized in a similar way to `ParametricPlot3D`.

**EDIT** I really liked the animation, but think the Cylinder by default masks the function. Perhaps the following is easier to see:

```
Animate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[α t], Sin[α t], 
      Sqrt[1 - α^2] t}, {Cos[α t], 
      Sin[α t], -Sqrt[1 - α^2] t}}, {α, -1, 1}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2 π, 2 π}}, 
      Axes -> False, BoxStyle -> Opacity[0]], 
    Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Yellow, Opacity[0.2], 
      Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2 π}, {0, 0, 2 π}}, 1]}]
  ], 
{t, 0, 2 π}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick nicely. Much appreciated.